# parsing continuous string using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Could any of you help me get the integer (layer,ieta,depth) in this line using sscanf? I've used a separate function before (1) and it worked. But i just wanted to try something new instead (2) and the program returns 0 for each variables.

(1)

```
Int_t getIetaFromHistName (string histName)
{

Int_t IetaPos = histName.find("_Ieta"); //find position of Ieta & return as integer
Int_t IphiPos = histName.find("_Iphi");
return atoi(histName.substr(IetaPos+5,IphiPos-IetaPos-5).c_str()); //reconstruct the string (post of 1st char to be copied, string length)

};
```

(2)

```
char histoName [100] = event2->GetName();
sscanf(histoName,"H2_HB_PHI12_LAYER%d_SRCTUBE_Ieta%d_Iphi12_Depth%d",&layNo,&ietaNo,&depthNo); //string histoName = H2_HB_PHI12_LAYER10_SRCTUBE_Ieta1_Iphi12_Depth1
printf("Layer= %d , Ieta= %d , Depth= %d\n",layNo,ietaNo,depthNo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize a string like this:

```
char histoName [100] = event2->GetName();
```

It needs to be:

```
char histoName [100];
strcpy(histoName, event2->getName());
```